# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea and resizing window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user-interface, aero

I'm using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` to have a nice look of my windows, but there is a 'glitch' while resizing window - when things are scaling, for small amount of time there is visible background, which's treated as black when I have property `Background="Transparent"` set.

How to get rid of this problem? Of course I could extend margins to cover much more than strictly needed amount of a window, but I feel it'd be too CPU-consuming.

Comment: Did you try `HwndSource.FromHwnd(WINDOWHANDLE).CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIK now - there is no such solution - after size change borders have to be extended and Aero cares about it, leaving no way to change it.